# Portrait image is not properly resizing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigraphicscontext

landscape is properly resizing but Portrait image is not resizing properly. 
Please somebody help me to sort out this problem.
code :-

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width*image.scale;

float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height*image.scale;

NSLog(@" image size %f %f %f",image.size.width,image.size.height,image.scale);

if(widthRatio > heightRatio)

    newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);

 else

    newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/mustangostang/UIImage-ResizeMagick its awesome

Comment: please check the imageView frame is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image imageSize:(CGSize)size {
    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat requiredWidth = (imageWidth * size.height) / imageHeight;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(requiredWidth, size.height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, requiredWidth, size.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something very similar issue few days back. I was trying to set larger dimension image in smaller dimension `UIImageView` using `resizeImage` method as mentioned in one of the answer here. But it could not solve my problem. So here is what I used to solve my problem,

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[yourImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

OR

```
[yourImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
yourImageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight );
[yourImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Yes it will not scale your image, but your image would not be squished. I solved my problem using this, hopes it might solve your problem.